# Need to solve a MYSQL select query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    points.location_id,
    route_locations.route_id

FROM
    points
LEFT JOIN route_locations ON route_locations.location_id = points.location_id
WHERE
    points.id = 199 OR points.id = 205
```

after this query I am getting this result..

```
route_id    location_id
12            69
12            75
14            75
```

now I need the common value for location_id 69 and location_id 75.. ( here route_id 12)
How can I get that by Query..

Comment: show your expected result in table format

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: I just need the route_id which common for both location_id..@fahmi

Comment: mysql 5.7 @akina

Comment: The amount of points is an example (may be more than 2), or always 2 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below query -

```
    SELECT
        route_locations.route_id
    FROM points
    JOIN route_locations ON route_locations.location_id = points.location_id
    WHERE
        points.id in (199,205) 
    group by route_locations.route_id
    having count(points.location_id)=2
```

Comment: yes those value should be query result not parameters .. @Fahimi

Comment: LEFT JOIN is illogical. Replace it with INNER one.